# Problems with xBox360 Controller and xpad

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, lubuntu

my HTPC works with Kodibuntu 14, which is a Lubuntu 14.04 with Kodi. I want us it as a Console for some old game (NES, Gameboy, ...) with my xBox360-Wireless-Controller. xpad finds the Controller, but there are some problems:

- when i connect the controller before starting the machine, xpad finfs the controller, but the kodi home screen runs to the right (or left) side like i press the cursor button all the time. this ends after i press a button on the controller. after that i can i the controller.
- all 4 LEDs are blinking all the time. normally (on windows) this indicates that the controller isn't connected to the receiver - but on linux it works, but all LEDs are blinking.
- how can i map the controllers buttons to some buttons of the keyboard? i will use emulators and they can be controlled by keyboard, so i think the best way is to simulate a keyboard. the reactions of the controllers buttons are very sensitive, not easy to use.

i've tried xboxdrv before and it worked better for some of the problems, but it only works when i start it manually in terminal (not possible on my HTPC) or when the controller is connected before i start the HTPC.

Comment: In lubuntu xpad is a notetacking app for writing sticky notes but this question seems like there might be two things called xpad making this question a bit confusing. Is there something called xpad taht is for xbox controlles to see if they are connecting. Also is this machine connected to a lan or the interetnet. Not that most older consoles were. Also do you have a desktop or other external monitor with a free not used input so maybe you could debug even if means moving the htpc to another room to get it working. CAn you get a mouse cursor, if so you can get keyboard input thourhg onboard.

Comment: yes, what i mean is the xpad kernel module for usingthe xbox controller on linux.

Comment: the htpc is connected to the internet, but i don't think this is the problem. the htpc is the only machine with a linux i have. i can connect the htpc to the monitor, but i don't understand how this could help. i can use a mouse and keyboard on the htpc, thats not the problem. the problem is, that the xbox controller.